# Share a file for C# project at home and at office

Tags: c#, .net, svn, version-control, project-management

I have formed a number of source code files as my library. For example, I wrote *LinqExtension.cs* providing *Median()* function.

Now I'm working on a project which needs LinqExtension.cs. As usually, I link the file to the project. As introduced [here](http://greenicicleblog.com/2010/12/01/link-whole-directories-into-visual-studio-projects/). The reason that I link files rather than copying them is to keep the files at a single location. If I modify a file, all dependent projects get affected.

I also add the project to Subversion and upload to and download from Google Code. The linked file is not under version control.

I work on the project at home as well as at office. I hate copying the linked file to my office, which makes the file not single.

I figure out a solution that add `<Compile Include="http://www.example.com/LinqExtension.cs"/>` to csproj file so that the file only exists on the Internet. Once I upload a new verison of the file, all dependent projects get affected.  Unfortunately the solution doesn't work.

Any other suggesions or better practice?

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to share your core library at the binary level, rather than at source code.  You could set up a [private Nuget repository](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/10/21/hosting-your-own-local-and-remote-nupack-feeds.aspx) to make this easier.

If it is absolutely necessary to share files, you can use pre-build actions in your project to copy the file from a common location, or even download them from google code.  It's not clean, but if you don't want to use source control for it then I don't think you will find a clean way.

Comment: Some of my files only contain one method. The dll of the files should be 1KB, I think. Using these small DLLs may not be efficient. Plus, the methods in my file are internal. If the file has 100 internal methods, but I only use 1, the compiler under optimization mode will not compile the remaining 99 methods.  However, your "pre-build action" is useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep a library folder of binaries in my Dropbox. That way Common libraries that I use can be accessed from my home and work project workspaces and the service keeps the version up to date.